# How to preload classes in Java?

Tags: java, classloader, preload

The first opening of a new JInternalFrame in my Swing interface takes some time. According to the profiler, most of this time is spent in the Classloader.loadClass() method. I understand that it loads classes dynamically when needed and indeed the next time I open the same frame, it is much faster.

This application has a login screen, and then a time with an empty desktoppane before the user opens one of those internal frames. I figure that since I have some "down time", I could use it to preload some common classes in background, so that when the user actually opens an internal frame, it goes much faster.

Is there a way to achieve that, other than having to generate an entire path of "dummy contructors" through my panels and actually initialize an instance of those classes?

*Ideally, if it could cascade such loading, it would be even better. A bit like the work done by classfileset in ant*

Comment: [ClassLoader#loadClass](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ClassLoader.html#loadClass(java.lang.String))

Comment: I did this issue with JasperReports. What I did was to create a dummy report preload its jars and dependencies

Comment: There is a [ClassPreloader](https://github.com/jermainexu/ClassPreloader) that you can use to customize your class preloading. For example load any class starts with some strings, regex or in some packages.

Comment: @StarPinkER - interesting! Thanks for the link, I'll give it a look

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're not doing anything special with classloaders, you can call `Class.forName(String className)` for each class you want to pre-load.

This will execute static initializers in those classes, so it could affect the behaviour of your program (although I'd consider any such program to be badly-written).

Comment: Seems to do the trick indeed (no issues with static hopefully). Now to find a smart way to get the dependencies for some root classes...